# How can I cite a title using the bibliography style {abbrvnat}?

Tags: citing

I am currently writing my thesis and the template of our chair uses the

```
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
```

and I also have the

```
\RequirePackage[round,
                sort&compress]{natbib}
```

in the .cls file.

Other references on the internet showed `\citetitle`, but it does not work and up till now I did not find a solution.

I search for it periodically when I need it, but due to lack of results, I find other solutions like rephrasing or hard coding....

Thanks a lot, this site provided a lot of answers to me before!

Cheers from Germany!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Which citation management package (if any) do you use? `natbib`, maybe? LaTeX, by default, only provides the instruction `\cite` to create citation call-outs. Various LaTeX citation-related packages provide additional citation-related instructions; e.g., `natbib` provides the following instructions, among others: `\citet`, `\citep`, `citeauthor`, and `citeyear`.  Your statement that "Other references on the internet showed `\citetitle`" isn't exactly specific -- *where* on the Internet did you come across the `\citetitle` instruction?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. In particular how to create a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407) could be useful for improving your question.

Comment: Hi guys, sorry I forgot that one. Yeah it is natbib. Sorry I don't recall the exact link where I found it, must've been around here somewhere. 
So is it possible to do with my configuration? I believe not....

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [usebib](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/usebib) package and set up a `\citetitle` macro yourself, as is demonstrated in the following example.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mybib.bib}
@article{abc,
  author = {Author, Anne},
  title  = {{Random Thoughts}},
  journal= {Circularity Today},
  year   = 5001,
  volume = 1,
  number = 2,
  pages  = {3-4},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[round,sort&compress]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\usepackage{usebib} 
\bibinput{mybib} % specify name of bib file, w/o ".bib" extension
\newcommand\citetitle[1]{\usebibentry{#1}{title}}

\begin{document}
\emph{\citetitle{abc}}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Will I be able to use this in addition to the natbib package?

Comment: @James -- Yes indeed.